Confusion about normal covering spaces
I struggle with understanding and using the following definition. A covering space $p:\tilde{X} \to X$ is called normal if for each $x \in X$ and each pair of lifts $\tilde{x}$,$\tilde{x}'$ of x there is a deck transformation taking $\tilde{x}$ to $\tilde{x}'$. For example the following picture shows a nonnormal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$. How can I see its nonnormal and how do I use the definition to show it.$S^1 \vee S^1$" />

To see why this covering space is not normal, pick a convenient point on your picture there and project it down to $S^1\vee S^1$. You will see that it has 4 different lifts in your covering space. Can you construct a homeomorphism taking each one of these lifts to each other one?
No. To see why not, notice that a homeomorphism of this covering space can be obtained by basically rotating and permuting these circles because it must send $a$ segments to other $a$ segments, $b$ segments to $b$ segments, and permute the intersection points.
Here's an illustration:

I can build automorphisms by rotating the pink/purple and blue/green, or the red/orange/yellow/brown circles.
However, you should convince yourself that you can't build a continuous automorphism which basically swaps the two "a" circles. It's either not a local homeomorphism or the orientations don't match. Pick your convenient point in one of these circles and there is no Deck transformation which maps the lift on one of them to the lift on the other.
To tell algebraically, you want to check that $\langle a^2, b^4, ab, bab^2b^{-1}, bab^{-2}\rangle$ is normal in $\langle a,b\rangle$, which is more procedural, but I don't think that was your question.
Edit: Here's a clearer picture with labels, maybe the colorings on the last picture made it unclear.

I can make an automorphism that sends $\tilde{x}_1$ to $\tilde{x}_4$. There it is. Let me try to make an automorphism that sends $\tilde{x}_1$ to $\tilde{x}_3$. Without even trying to color it, I can see that it reverses the orientations so it's already impossible.
Because it has to be a local homeomorphism near $\tilde{x}_1$, that commutes with $p$, it has to send the (orange) $b$ segment leaving $\tilde{x}_1$ to the (red) $b$ segment leaving $\tilde{x}_3$. But this can't be done in a consistent way that doesn't mess up the local pictures.

I still have some confusion. When I apply $a$ I only rotate both pink/purple and blue/green circles simultaneously, when I apply $b$ I rotate the red/orange/yellow/brown circle. To get the top right cover(refering to your drawing right now) from the top left cover I would need to somehow move, in particular the green arrow from top left cover to top right cover but as there is no $a$ on the  red/orange/yellow/brown circle I cant do that. Is that it or am I missing something?

That's kinda right. Think about a neighborhood of a point that you map between the two circles. Since it's a homeo, it takes a neighborhood of that point with it. But this forces what happens to the whole segment (unique path lifting property). I'll add a picture with labels
